# How to get the maximum Double value of a tuple array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Currently I have a tuple array defined as `var myArray = [(Date, Double)]()`.

The output of `myArray` might look something like this:

```
[(2016-08-30 07:00:00 +0000, 1.0), (2016-09-30 07:00:00 +0000, 0.050000000000000003), 
(2016-10-30 07:00:00 +0000, 20.0), (2017-06-30 07:00:00 +0000, 6.0), 
(2017-07-30 07:00:00 +0000, 5.0)]
```

I am trying to get the max `Double` value from the array of tuples but not sure how to go about it.

I see there is a function:

```
myArray.max { (<#(Date, Double)#>, <#(Date, Double)#>) -> Bool in 

}
```

However, I'm not exactly sure how to use it if that even is the right function to use?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`max` works similar to `sort`. You have to pass a comparison `$0 < $1`. The result is the (optional) tuple with the maximum value.

```
if let maxItem = myArray.max(by: {$0.1 < $1.1 }) {
    let maxDouble = maxItem.1
}
```

Once again, you are discouraged from using tuples as a data source

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309):

> If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution

```
let max = myArray.max { (left, right) -> Bool in
    return left.1 < right.1
}
```

Or use the $ syntax

```
myArray.max { $0.1 < $1.1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a closure to `max` . .

```
let maxTuple = myArray.max{ $0.1 < $1.1 }!
let maxDouble = maxTuple.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myArray.max { (val1, val2) -> Bool in
    return val1.1 < val2.1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the max double from the given array

```
var myArray = [(2016-08-30, 1.0), (2016-09-30, 0.050000000000000003),
 (2016-10-30, 20.0), (2017-06-30, 6.0),
 (2017-07-30, 5.0)]
// Get maximum element

var max = myArray.max {
    $0.1 < $1.1
}

print(max!.1)
```